# How to write the code for Clear Email Client settings in android?

Tags: android, email, settings

[image]I am working on chat related application in this application share the information to email default any mail client its working fine ,in this application i am adding settings in settings one option is adding "Clear Email Client settings"  suppose click on this again show the dialog for default choose mail option .
How to clear the email settings in android ?please send me any solution.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        i.setType("text/html"); 
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail from Mobile Application"); 

        String emailbody="";

        emailbody=String.format("<html>"+
                "<head>"+
                "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0;'>"+
                "</head>"+
                "<body> " +
                "<b>Reference : </b> %s"+"<br><br>" +
                "</body>"+
                "</html>",
                s_ref);

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(emailbody));

        try { 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...")); 
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can't be done anymore. Since Gingerbread, Android doesn't provides the developers access to a certain method called `clearApplicationUserData(String packageName, learUserDataObserver mClearDataObserver)`. So you can't do that without any illegal hacks.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10246711/2310111)